# django admin forms readonly_fields - can't save if required

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-models, django-validation

I'm using a customized form in the admin, with many readonly fields depending on logged in user's permissions.

Now, if I try to save the form logged in as a non-supersuser, I have a `this field is required error` for all required fields that are readonly.

It's really strange since I never experienced this before. 
Any help on that?

Comment: You'll need to post the code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, solved - tnx anyway: I was overriding the `get_form` method in the modelAdmin in the wrong way, without passing `obj` arg -> `def get_form(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` instaead of `def get_form(self, request, obj=None, *args, **kwargs)`